# Dealing with different screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo

As a natural part of writing a real-time game for Android, I'll need to be able to support various screen resolutions, densities, etc.

From the [primary article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in the Android SDK Documentation, I'm aware that I should create separate resource for each bitmap in my game, to accommodate different screen densities; but I don't quite understand what to do about positions, velocities, etc.

The document says that I should use density-independent units in my code wherever I use explicit values. But doesn't that mean I would need to convert absolute pixels to density-independent units *every single time* that I use an explicit value?

For instance, I am developing a game (in landscape) using a high-density 800x480 display. Now, I am comfortable with moving a sprite at 1 pixel per frame (*after* delta time, etc). So that would look like:

```
sprite.setVelocityX(1);
```

If I were to use density-independent units, like the documentation suggests, wouldn't I have to do something like this **everywhere** that I use an explicit number?

```
sprite.setVelocityX(convert(1));

public float convert(float value)
{
    return value * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

It feels like I'm not understanding this correctly...

Comment: NO idea if this helps, but iOS handles this natively with the concept of points. You define your screen elements in points. iOS then converts those to pixels. 1pt = 1px on standard screen. 1pt = 4px on retina display screen. Hopefully android offers this type of conversion built in (otherwise it does sound like a PITA to deal with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience in animation, but the first idea that comes to my head is to define a unit as a

```
static int UNIT = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

and then use it as

```
sprite.setVelocityX(3*UNIT); // replaces sprite.setVelocityX(3);
```

That way you create an int once and avoid querying `DisplayMetrics` every time.

That said, there might be OpenGL or AndEngine mechanisms to get density-independent values directly.

Comment: Ugh, I guess this really is the only way to do this!

Comment: @Jesse call it `static int pt` and then you have exactly what DA commented for IOS ;)